# Inheritance or Struct into Struct

Tags: c++

I wonder what's the difference between:

```
struct A
{
  struct B{};
};
```

and:

```
struct A{};

struct B:A{};
```

Comment: Welcome! This question appears to be a general programming question, not a security question. It would be better question for StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet `B` is nested struct in `A`, hence if you need to creat objects out of them you should do as follows

```
A a;//A object
A::B b;//B object
```

In the second snippet `B` inherits from `A`, hence if you need to creat objects out of them you should do as follows

```
A a;//A object
B b;//B object
```

and in the second case all of `A` members (if there are) will be members of `B` too  because `A` is the base struct.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @asmmo answer:

The inheritance can have different visibilities (public, private or protected).
The declaration is (only using the key word):

```
struct A{};

struct B: public A{};
```

If you don't specify it, the inheritance will be private. 
What does this mean?

If:

```
struct A{
void func(){}
};

struct B: public A{};
```

Any object of type `B` can call the function `func()` with `b.func();`
If it is private you can only call `func()` inside the definition of `B` but `B`-typed objects can't call it. 
If it is protected you can only call `func()` inside the definition of `B` and structs that inherit from `B`, but not their instances.

So, if your are testing inheritance, you may start doing them all `public` and then get more specific when needed.